# Using struct in String over and over again (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

I have a string that contains multiple groups of data. I want to use a struct on it to be able to divide the data and be able to manipulate it. So far, I don't know how to manipulate the array. The data contains a 4-character name and age. Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>                           
#include <stdlib.h>                         
#include <string.h>                         

typedef struct structtest                   
{                                           
 unsigned char name[4];                 
 unsigned char age[2];
} structtest;                               
structtest       *dstr;                     

int main( void )                            
{                                                                                          
    char test[18] = 'mark20john18josh16';   

     //clueless on this part                                   

    return(0);                              
}
```

Comment: Please be much more specific, add any code that you have now since that often helps in understanding. What is a "group"? What "array"?

Comment: what type of manipulation you need? please give some more explanation about your requirement.

Comment: I want to know how to use the struct on the char array over and over again. @HeenaGoyal

Comment: @entendezEJ: Maybe you should follow a C tutorial first.

Answer (score 1):

Usually to serialize any memory to char array, you need to write it's size (for example LONG32 - 4 bytes) and then string/memory itself. When read - first read size, then you know how much you need read then.

For using char array for structures:
Try this:

```
int i;
char* yourstring = (char*)malloc(N);
YourStruct* p = (YourStruct*)yourstring;
//Do something
while (i < sizeof(yourstring) / sizeof(YourStruct))
{
    ++p;
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: according to code you added, try this:

structtest* pstruct = test; and then move over as I wrote above